# Problems with the path of the auto import feature in VSCode in nextjs14 projects

Tags: typescript

While working on the nextjs14 project, I manually modified the directory to switch to a project structure using the src folder.

So the path to the auto import? function in vscode is coming out weird.

The path that currently comes out:
@//components/ui/button

Path I want:
@/components/ui/button

It's probably something in the path settings, but I'm not sure.